# What does Kapiushon mean?

Tags: dialogue, arrowverse, arrow

In season 6 episode 17 of *Arrow*. Anatoly says Kapiushon. So I’m wondering what it means because it says Kapiushon in other episodes and so I’m confused when they say this.

Comment: Related: [Russian words in the titles of an American TV series footages](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70481/27264)

Comment: @AJ  but that question was weird/broad and the answer didn't elaborate much and received badly.

Answer (score 5):

For Russian word for Hood is [Капюшо́н](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BD) (Capuchon) which is not far from Kapiushon, which is also the title of [S05E17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapiushon). Also, Anatoly uses it to refer it to Oliver who is also used to be called hood.

The same episode was titled [Kapot](https://mobile.twitter.com/mguggenheim/status/826089072649138176) first which also means "hood" or "a car hood". Капюшо́н seems like a more accurate word for English word Hood.

Even in S08E05, Oliver said:

> Kapiushon is a nickname that the Bratva gave me. It means "hood".

Comment: I avoided S08E05 spoilers and this line was barely spoiling anything.